# visual studio 2010 Pending Changes filter by file extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have almost 776 files have been edited in auto upgrade from vs2008 to vs2010. Is there a way i can filter my pending changes by file type. So i can revert specific file type which was not needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in VS, but you could do it in command line, using [tf undo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4.aspx) command.

```
tf undo [/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]] 
 [/recursive] itemspec [/noprompt] [/login:username, [password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```

For example, navigate to directory into which you downloaded your workspace and undo as follows:

```
tf undo /recursive *.aspx
```